# Merging Two Libraries in C++

Tags: c++, header, libraries

I have two separate libraries with different functionalities like A.h and B.h. I want to combine these both libraries into App.h

When the user declare the instance of App Class. How should it knows that it has to create the instance of A.h or B.h

Comment: When you call `new A` or `new B`? What's the question?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher The new A or new B will be created on the instantiation of App Class. It should be implicitly returned the class to App class type.

Comment: A and B are different types, you could use a std::variant<A, B> with a factory function.

Comment: @SameedTariq Could you please frame a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming))?

Assuming A and B are classes and share a common interface (C), your App class can do something like this:

```
static C create_A_or_B()
{
    if (...)
        return A()
    else
        return B()
}
```